# Ordering by a field not in the select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, sql-order-by

I need to create a query that pulls only the customer_no column (because the software restrictions are as such, and I can't code it externally). But I need to be able to sort the data by create_dt (in reverse) column. The code/SQL is restricting me in using the following because in order to sort by something that data has to appear int the select statement.

I can't have it appear there – is there any way around this?

```
 Select Distinct top 3500 a.customer_no 
  From T_CUSTOMER a  WITH (NOLOCK)
  JOIN (Select a1.customer_no From VXS_CUST_TKW a1 WITH (NOLOCK) Where a1.tkw in (141)) as e ON      e.customer_no = a.customer_no
  Where 1 = 1
 order by a.create_dt desc
```

Comment: I've never had that problem with MySQL. On the other hand, MySQL doesn't have `TOP 3500`, you have to use `LIMIT 3500` at the end of the query. Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: Its transact SQL. I believe. I'm working though a software - on the front end. That said the top 3500 works without issue - but the sorting doesn't work.

Comment: You're WHERE clause has no use why is it there?

Comment: Are you aware of the ramifications of tossing NOLOCK on every query? You can and will get missing and/or duplicate rows. http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/

Comment: @JohnRuddell the system creates syntax on its own - but when we need to filter/modify it - which is often - we open it up in code mode and make changes. But we try not to make too many changes because we don't always have the ability to test it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course you can.  Your query looks like SQL Server, where this will likely do what you want:

```
  Select top 3500 a.customer_no 
  From T_CUSTOMER a  WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN
       (Select a1.customer_no
        From VXS_CUST_TKW a1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        Where a1.tkw in (141)
       ) e
       ON e.customer_no = a.customer_no
  Where 1 = 1
  group by a.customer_no
  order by max(a.create_dt) desc;
```

The equivalent query in MySQL would look like:

```
  Select a.customer_no 
  From T_CUSTOMER a JOIN
       (Select a1.customer_no
        From VXS_CUST_TKW a1 
        Where a1.tkw in (141)
       ) e
       ON e.customer_no = a.customer_no
  Where 1 = 1
  order by a.create_dt desc
  limit 3500;
```

I removed the `distinct` because it may not be necessary.  If it is, add it back in.

Comment: I use your query - the first one and it seemed to work but as soon as I added Distinct after the word select i got the following error: Order By items must appear in the select list if select distinct is specified (-1) and i can't seem to get rid of that.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR . . . The easiest solution is to use `group by` instead of `distinct`.  I modified the first query.

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like mysql.

Anyway... you could try an ordered sub-select IE

```
From (select * from T_CUSTOMER order by create_dt) a WITH (NOLOCK)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery that includes the column you're ordering by. Then the main query can just return the column you care about:

```
SELECT customer_no
FROM (
    Select top 3500 a.customer_no, a.create_dt
      From T_CUSTOMER a  WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN
           (Select a1.customer_no
            From VXS_CUST_TKW a1 WITH (NOLOCK)
            Where a1.tkw in (141)
           ) e
           ON e.customer_no = a.customer_no
      Where 1 = 1
      order by a.create_dt desc
)
```