# Is it good to add Group By and Order By columns in Index for MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have Composite Index on columns which are in Where clause of the query but should I add Group By and Order By columns in the Index?

For example I have a query:

```
select c1, c2
from table t1
where c3 = "A"
and c4 = "B"
Group By c1
Order By c5
```

My current Index is on c3 and c4 (in same order as query). Should I add c1 and c4 in the Index to improve the query performance?

Comment: The query is (a little) nonsensical, which renders the question nonsensical too. A good rule-of-thumb is 'if you don't have any aggregating functions then you don't need a GROUP BY clause'. If you want to return only DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT.

Comment: Its difficult to answer the question with such little context, but as a general suggestion, I'd recommend using EXPLAIN in order to determine which indices are used for a given query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html

Comment: Probably learn how to use `GROUP BY`.  It serves no purpose without any aggregation.

Comment: As Strawberry said your hypothetical query is impractical. Moreover, it will be invalid and throw error due to non-aggregated and non-selected field used in Order By clause. Anyways, if you are looking for some tips on indexing, you may read this: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: The example query is kind of funny, but I think the real question here is whether mysql uses indexes to optimize group by/order by? The order by aspect is answered here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/order-by-column-should-have-index-or-not

Comment: @Strawberry agree with you. It was by mistake. I have update my question.

Comment: Now it's worse. :-(

Comment: Your edited query returns an indeterminate result. This is illegal in most versions of SQL, and illegal by default in the latest version of MySQL.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you said "it will be invalid and throw error due to non-aggregated and non-selected field used in Order By clause". That is not correct. MySQL is not throwing any error if non-selected field is being used in Order By clause. Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789703/ordering-by-a-field-not-in-the-select-statement-in-sql

Comment: @Another_Dev older versions of MySQL were slacky and neglected these basic errors..upgrade to the latest version and observe the difference for yourself

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

```
where c3 = "A"
  and c4 = "B"
Group By c1
Order By c5
```

Can make use of either of these:

```
INDEX(c3, c4, c1)
INDEX(c4, c3, c1)
```

It cannot get past `GROUP BY` to get to `ORDER BY` (unless they are the same).

On the other hand, this is harder to optimize:

```
where c3 > "A"   -- note the inequality (a "range")
  and c4 = "B"
Group By c1
Order By c5
```

This is best:

```
INDEX(c4, c3)   -- the order matters now: '=' first
```

Further:

```
where c3 = "A"
  and c4 = "B"
Group By c1
Order By c1     -- same as GROUP BY
LIMIT 10        -- now can get to this
```

This will stop after 10 rows if you have

```
INDEX(c3, c4, c1) or INDEX(c4, c3, c1)
```

Adding a `LIMIT` to the other examples:  They would find all the rows, sort them, then deliver 10.

More discussion of optimal composite indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

To make the index "covering", tack on (at the end) any other columns in the query.  (But don't get carried away with this.  A Rule of Thumb: don't make an index of more than 5 columns.)  "Covering" adds an extra boost to the speed because the query can be performed entirely in the index's BTree.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,c1 INT NOT NULL
,c2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

SELECT DISTINCT c1
           FROM my_table t1
          WHERE c2 = 'A'
```

This query will benefit from a covering index on (c2,c1).

Note that this can be very easily tested - although, curiously, if you provide both indexes (c1,c2), and (c2,c1), it appears to pick the wrong one.