# Sort SQL output results by a column not in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a SQL query that works perfect for fetching the data needed. However I can not get it to Order by a column that is not present in the SELECT section. I found a similar question that was answered, but could not understand exactly what it was doing.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789703/ordering-by-a-field-not-in-the-select-statement-in-sql)

I'm trying to get the whole output to be sorted by 'CustomerLastName' but not have the that column show in the output file.

I have:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', CustomerNumber+'.'), LEN(CustomerNumber)),'D','CAFET','', sum(Total) as totalsales
FROM ViewDetailedSalesReport
WHERE DateSold BETWEEN ('20200101') AND DateADD(day,1,'20200131')
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
ORDER BY CustomerLastName ASC
```

I know from reading other articles that I can not Order by something that is not in the SELECT portion, but can't quite understand how to use a 'non-declared' column to order by.

Comment: *"I know from reading other articles that I can not Order by something that is not in the SELECT portion"* That isn't quite true. You *can* sort by columns that aren't in the `SELECT`, but in this case `CustomerLastName` isn't in your `GROUP BY` so it can't be. You just need to add `CustomerLastName` to the `GROUP BY` clause. as I *assume* `CustomerNumber` is unique to a customer.

Comment: Yes the `CustomerNumber` is unique, however the `CustomerLastName` is not, I was under the impression that the GROUP BY would be how the data is totaled together, thus I wouldn't want a non-uniqe field in that section?

So if I understand you correctly I should be able to use `GROUP BY CustomerNumber, CustomerLastName` `ORDER BY CustomerLastName ASC`

Is that how it would look?

Comment: I would expect so, yes (I can't see your data, so impossible for test).

Comment: And if a column is more unique than another, the. Grouping by the less unique won't change the aggregation. In this case `CustomerLastName` is going to be a consistent value for a given `CustomerNumber`, so won't change the end results.

Comment: That worked perfectly and was much simpler than I expected! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Thank you @Larnu for letting me know it was a simple fix by adding my CustomerLastName column to the Group By section. It now works exactly as expected.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', CustomerNumber+'.'), LEN(CustomerNumber)),'D','CAFET','', sum(Total) as totalsales
FROM ViewDetailedSalesReport
WHERE DateSold BETWEEN ('20200101') AND DateADD(day,1,'20200131')
GROUP BY CustomerNumber, CustomerLastName
ORDER BY CustomerLastName ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can order by something not in the `SELECT`.  The issue is the `GROUP BY`.  If you are not ordering by a `GROUP BY` key (or a column alias defined in the `SELECT`), then you need an aggregation function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CustomerNumber, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', CustomerNumber+'.'), LEN(CustomerNumber)),
       'D', 'CAFET', '',
       sum(Total) as totalsales
FROM ViewDetailedSalesReport
WHERE DateSold BETWEEN ('20200101') AND DateADD(day,1,'20200131')
GROUP BY CustomerNumber
ORDER BY MAX(CustomerLastName) ASC
```